# Maximum Principle Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, maximum-principle, mean-curvature-flows

I am reading the mean curvature flow from Mantegazza. The maximum principle is stated as follows:
[image]

Two questions:

Why does $ u_{\text{max}}:=\max u(p,t) $ exist? Why is there $T'$ instead of $T$ in the Cauchy problem?

Comment: It's stated in the paragraph that maximum exists (in $K$).